# File size limit for transferring data using Fuse ESB or apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

I have a doubt about the max file size that is allowed for transferring a file from Source to destination using FuseESB.

And if the file size is bigger that the limit, how to handle such file?

### EDITED

I am planning to use ESB for a lot of complicated processes.

And some of the process include

1. filtering the data.
2. transfer data from one form to another (eg: from excel sheet to xml format and then may be transferred to another format like csv)
3. There is also an encryption that is planned during the process

So does what ever suggestion that was made for ESB, still hold good for such a scenario?

Comment: You will be constrained by the jvm memory available if you are planning to load the whole file and perform a transformation.

Answer (score -1):

There is no file size limit in Camel. You can process as big files you want. Though mind if you read the file content into memory then very big files can possible not fit into the memory. You can process the files in streaming mode, such as FileInputStream etc.

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to update your question that is totally different than the title of this Q which is about file size limit. Instead create a new question for your new questions. And can you mark this question as answered, as there is NO file size limit in Fuse ESB.

Comment: here the question is still regarding how big the file can be if there are such processes involved as mentioned in the edit. and i ask if your statement still holds good if there are such processes involved. And generally if an application dont have limit, i thought there would have been a clause from application saying RAM size is limit or something like that.

Comment: Of course you are ALWAYS limited by physical capabilities such as memory/cpu/disk/network bandwith and so forth. But in Fuse ESB there is no file limit how big files you can process.